# Комментарии как заголовки в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Есть ли возможность организовать фолдинг по комментарию в android studio а-ля outline/outshine-mode в emacs?

Другими словами, такой код

```
class SomeClass {
    // * group of related methods 1
    void method1() { ... }
    void method2() { ... }
    void method3() { ... }
    void method4() { ... }

    // * group of related methods 2
    void method1() { ... }
    void method2() { ... }
    void method3() { ... }
    void method4() { ... }

    // * group of related methods 3
    void method1() { ... }
    void method2() { ... }
    void method3() { ... }
    void method4() { ... }

}
```

свернуть следующим образом

```
class SomeClass {
    // * group of related methods 1 ... (типо свернули)

    // * group of related methods 2
    void method1() { ... }
    void method2() { ... }
    void method3() { ... }
    void method4() { ... }

    // * group of related methods 3 ... (типо свернули)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте необходимый код в теги:

```
//<editor-fold desc="regionName">
code here...
//</editor-fold>
```

Слева появятся стрелочки и Вы сможете свернуть/развернуть данный регион.